# Binding a list of phone numbers in CQL IN() clause returns "CodecNotFoundException [TEXT <-> java.util.List<java.lang.String>]"

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I'm using the lastet datastax cassandra driver in my application:

```
     <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-driver-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.15.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
```

When the following code is executed:

```
    ...
    List<String> myList= new ArrayList<>();
    myList.add("+4911111111");

       final BoundStatement bs = prepareAndBind(cqlSession, "delete "
                + "from test.numbers "
                + "where id=:customerId "
                + "and phonenumbers in (:phoneNumbers) ")
                .setLong("customerId", customerId)               
                .setList("phoneNumbers", myList, String.class)
    ...
```

I get the exception:

```
  com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.type.codec.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found 
  for requested operation: [TEXT <-> java.util.List<java.lang.String>]
```

Using older versions of the cassandra driver this code was working. What is the best approach to create a statement with a `WHERE IN ()` clause in this driver version. Do I need to use a custom codec for this, or is there an easier way?

Comment: In the Cassandra table definition, what is the data type of the `phonenumbers` column?

Comment: The type of phonenumbers is "text"

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `phonenumbers` should be of cql data type `text` and you cannot use a Java type `List<String>` for it. It'd have to be `String`. See the data type mapping [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/core/#cql-to-java-type-mapping).

I've a table with schema as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE payloadtest.d (
    i int PRIMARY KEY,
    a list<text>
);
```

and my Java program using the same the same [`4.15.0` version of the driver](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/com.datastax.oss/java-driver-core/4.15.0).

My `pom.xml` dependency look like,

```
...
<properties>
  <java-driver>4.15.0</java-driver>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>${java-driver}</version>
    </dependency>
...
```

My code looked like,

```
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.BoundStatement;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.PreparedStatement;

public class ListValueExample {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        // Create the CqlSession object:
           try (CqlSession session = CqlSession.builder()
               .withCloudSecureConnectBundle(Paths.get("./src/main/resources/secure-connect-payloadtest.zip"))
               //R/W Role
               .withAuthCredentials("<ClientID>", "<ClientSecret>")
               .build()) {
               
               
               List<String> dalist = new ArrayList<>();
               dalist.add("+4911111111");
               PreparedStatement ps = session.prepare("INSERT INTO payloadtest.d(i,a) VALUES (?,?)");
               BoundStatement bs =
                        ps.boundStatementBuilder()
                            .setInt("i", 0)
                            .setList("a", dalist, String.class)
                            .build();
               session.execute(bs);
           }
           System.out.println("COMPLETED");
    }

}
```

and the result is:

```
token@cqlsh:payloadtest> select * from d;

 i | a
---+-----------------
 0 | ['+4911111111']

(1 rows)
```

So, you get the idea here. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Finally we found a solution. The problem is related to the braces used in the query. After changing:

```
 + "and phonenumbers in (:phoneNumbers) ")
```

to

```
 + "and phonenumbers in :phoneNumbers ")
```

it works.

Full example code:

```
...
List<String> myList= new ArrayList<>();
myList.add("+4911111111");

   final BoundStatement bs = prepareAndBind(cqlSession, "delete "
            + "from test.numbers "
            + "where id=:customerId "
            + "and phonenumbers in :phoneNumbers) "
            .setLong("customerId", customerId)               
            .setList("phoneNumbers", myList, String.class)
...
```